# How to get the latest record based on Timestamp in SQL Server with Join

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2012. I have a table (LocationResults) with multiple columns. I want to get all the columns that are also present in another table (TargetAssociationDetails) - but only those rows that were inserted the newest and are also present in the second table.

My TargetAssociationDetails table:

```
MSISDN        IMEI    IMSI
--------------------------
14085551107   NULL    NULL
14085551108   NULL    NULL
14085551113   NULL    NULL
```

My LocationResults table:

```
Latitude    Longitude       MSISDN        IMSI  IMEI    RecordedTimeStamp
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
57.785125   -123.40476      14085551107   NULL  NULL    05:54.8
57.78374111 -123.4027269    14085551107   NULL  NULL    19:12.6
57.78476194 -123.4045131    14085551107   NULL  NULL    09:08.3
57.61768861 -123.4081439    14085551108   NULL  NULL    19:08.4
57.801585   -123.45619      14085551114   NULL  NULL    19:08.5
57.55303194 -123.3019161    14085551113   NULL  NULL    19:08.5
```

This is my query -

```
SELECT MAX(lr.RecordTimestamp) AS RecordedTimeStamp, lr.IMEI, lr.IMSI, lr.MSISDN 
FROM LocationResults lr LEFT OUTER JOIN TargetAssosiationDetails tad ON 
tad.IMEI = lr.IMEI AND tad.IMSI = lr.IMSI AND tad.MSISDN = lr.MSISDN
GROUP BY lr.IMEI, lr.IMSI,lr.MSISDN
```

But in this case, I'm not able to get all the columns. I'm only able to get those columns that I'm grouping by.

The result I want is -

```
Latitude    Longitude       MSISDN        IMSI  IMEI    RecordedTimeStamp
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
57.78374111 -123.4027269    14085551107   NULL  NULL    19:12.6
57.61768861 -123.4081439    14085551108   NULL  NULL    19:08.4
57.55303194 -123.3019161    14085551113   NULL  NULL    19:08.5
```

I'm absolutely new to DB querying so it will be great if you can post a script along with an explanation of what it does.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want the latest timestamp with respect to which other columns?

Comment: it is always goo to tag the version of your sql server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you're using MS SQL Server 2008 or above you can use the window function [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms186734.aspx) to achieve these results. The ROW_NUMBER() function allows you to number each row according to a specific order (in this case the time stamp descending) and restart that ordering based on a value (in this case MSISDN): So for every distinct value of MSISDN number the rows in order from the highest Timestamp to the least. Then do an inner join to that query from your LocationResults table **ONLY** where the row number is 1 because that means it is the newest row.

Since it seems that each row is identified by three fields rather than one you'll need to partition your row by those three fields as well as using them in the join. This is done simply by listing them separated by commas in the PARTITION BY clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM LocationResults AS lr
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT *,
        -- number the rows based on the time stamp descending and restart the ordering for each MSISDN value
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MSISDN, IMEI, IMSI ORDER BY RecordedTimeStamp DESC) AS rnum
    FROM TargetAssociationDetails
) AS d ON d.MSISDN=lr.MSISDN
    AND d.IMEI=lr.IMEI
    AND d.IMSI=lr.IMSI
    -- join on row number 1 because that will be the newest row
    AND d.rnum=1
```

Comment: I've updated the question to show a relationship that exists with another table and I also need the condition to be applied on 3 fields - MSISDN, IMEI and IMSI.

Comment: Then update the join condition with the additional fields. My code is just an example of using the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to retrieve the newest record from a table. If you don't know how to do that you might ask another question but I'd recommend trying to read up on how table joins in SQL work first as your new question would likely get closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @yazz after a bit of thought I realized you also need to update the PARTITION BY clause and the JOIN condition if your rows are identified as unique by multiple fields. I've updated my answer to reflect that. Though your sample data shows only NULLs in those columns which means your joins won't work (because NULL != NULL). So if that is the case you'll need to handle those NULLs in your join condition or rethink how your rows are joined.

Comment: This worked perfectly, except I had to invert TargetAssociationDetails (it does not have RecordedTimestamp) and LocationResults. I handled the NULLs in the Join condition.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
;with cte as (
select Latitude, Longitude, MSISDN, IMSI, IMEI, RecordedTimeStamp
  , row_number() over (partition by MSISDN, order by RecordedTimeStamp desc) as RN
from LocationResults
)
select *
from cte 
where RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it.Below is one way which doesnt require CTE or derived tables..

```
select top 1 with ties Latitude, Longitude, MSISDN, IMSI, IMEI, RecordedTimeStamp
from 
LocationResults
order by  row_number() over (partition by MSISDN, order by RecordedTimeStamp desc)
```

Comment: I'm still not able to apply this query to include a relationship it has with another table. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

As ***Mike D.*** mentioned there're many ways to do it. Here's my approach:

```
DECLARE
    @TargetAssociationDetails TABLE (
                                        MSISDN  BIGINT,
                                        IMEI    VARCHAR(100),
                                        IMSI    VARCHAR(100)
                                    )

DECLARE
    @LocationResults    TABLE   (
                                    Latitude            FLOAT,
                                    Longitude           FLOAT,
                                    MSISDN              BIGINT,
                                    IMSI                VARCHAR(100),
                                    IMEI                VARCHAR(100),
                                    RecordedTimeStamp   DATETIME
                                )

INSERT INTO @LocationResults (Latitude, Longitude, MSISDN, IMSI, IMEI, RecordedTimeStamp)
VALUES (57.785125, -123.40476, 14085551107, NULL, NULL, '05:54.8')

INSERT INTO @LocationResults (Latitude, Longitude, MSISDN, IMSI, IMEI, RecordedTimeStamp)
VALUES (57.78374111, -123.4027269, 14085551107, NULL, NULL, '19:12.6')

INSERT INTO @LocationResults (Latitude, Longitude, MSISDN, IMSI, IMEI, RecordedTimeStamp)
VALUES (57.78476194, -123.4045131, 14085551107, NULL, NULL, '09:08.3')

INSERT INTO @LocationResults (Latitude, Longitude, MSISDN, IMSI, IMEI, RecordedTimeStamp)
VALUES (57.61768861, -123.4081439, 14085551108, NULL, NULL, '19:08.4')

INSERT INTO @LocationResults (Latitude, Longitude, MSISDN, IMSI, IMEI, RecordedTimeStamp)
VALUES (57.801585, -123.45619, 14085551114, NULL, NULL, '19:08.5')

INSERT INTO @LocationResults (Latitude, Longitude, MSISDN, IMSI, IMEI, RecordedTimeStamp)
VALUES (57.55303194, -123.3019161, 14085551113, NULL, NULL, '19:08.5')

INSERT INTO @TargetAssociationDetails (MSISDN, IMEI, IMSI)
VALUES (14085551107, NULL, NULL)

INSERT INTO @TargetAssociationDetails (MSISDN, IMEI, IMSI)
VALUES (14085551108, NULL, NULL)

INSERT INTO @TargetAssociationDetails (MSISDN, IMEI, IMSI)
VALUES (14085551113, NULL, NULL)

SELECT
    LR.Latitude,
    LR.Longitude,
    TAD.MSISDN,
    TAD.IMSI,
    TAD.IMEI,
    LR.RecordedTimeStamp
FROM @TargetAssociationDetails TAD
    INNER JOIN  (
                    SELECT
                        MAX(LR.RecordedTimeStamp) AS RecordedTimeStamp,
                        LR.MSISDN
                    FROM @LocationResults LR
                    GROUP BY
                        LR.MSISDN
                ) _LR ON _LR.MSISDN = TAD.MSISDN
    INNER JOIN @LocationResults LR ON [_LR].MSISDN = LR.MSISDN AND [_LR].RecordedTimeStamp = LR.RecordedTimeStamp
```

But I've to be fair, I'd have used Mike's way. It's one join lesser and a good example.

Answer (score 0):

When available dor use, as it is here, `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()`  to locate just the rows you require.

Then you can join to the related table(s). Here is an example using a "derived table":

```
SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT *,
        row_number() over (partition by MSISDN, order by RecordedTimeStamp desc)  as rowno
    FROM LocationResults 
     ) as lr 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TargetAssosiationDetails tad ON tad.IMEI = lr.IMEI AND tad.IMSI = lr.IMSI AND tad.MSISDN = lr.MSISD
WHERE lr.rowno = 1
```

Others have proposed a "common table expression" (CTE - these require using `WITH ... AS`) but there is no advantage in using that approach.  Personally I believe it is important for relative newbies to SQL to understand and be comfortable with derived tables before using CTEs indiscriminately.